# How to combine value match and pipeline operator in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

### Example

This is an example document:

```
{
  row: [
    {
      identifier: "a"
      value: 52
    },
    {
      identifier: "b"
      value: 22
    },
    {
      identifier: "c"
      value: 36 
    }
  ]
}
```

### Problem

Let's say I need the arrays first (`identifier` c) and last element (`identifier` c) but only where `value` is greater than 5 within the last element (`identifier` c).

Basically, I would like to combine these two conditions:

- Be `identifier a` or `identifier c`
- be greater than 5 when you are `identifier c`.

Both conditions should be part of an aggregation pipeline. The result should look like this:

```
[
  { 
    _id: 1, 
    row: [{ identifier: "a", value: 52}, { identifier: "c", value: 22}] 
  } //, ...
]
```

### Approach

I tried many ways but nothing worked. Last thing I tried was `$cond`, but that also didn't work:

```
'if': {
  'row.identifier': c,
  'then': {
    'row.value': {$gt: 5}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please review the problem statement for typos. It makes little sense in current edition. It might be simpler to express your requirements if you code the logic in vanilla javascript. E.g a function that accepts the array and returns the required result.

Comment: What exactly would you want to get as a return document?

Comment: Did you try 'row.identifier': 'c'  ?

Comment: @dnickless sorry, I added the wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how can filter the `row` array to only contain what you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        row: { // create a new field called "row" which will hold...
            $filter: { // ...the filtered contents...
                input: "$row", // ...of the existing "row" array...
                as: "this", // ...use the variable "$$this" to refer to the current element...
                cond: { // ...and only keep items where...
                    $or: [ // ...either...
                        { $eq: [ "$$this.identifier", "a" ] }, // ...the "identifier" field is equal to "a"...
                        { $and: [ // ...or both...
                            { $eq: [ "$$this.identifier", "c" ] }, // ...the "identifier" field is equal to "c"...
                            { $gt: [ "$$this.value", 5 ] } // ...and the "value" field is greater than 5
                        ]}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Nice, this looks very promising. Why are there two dollar signs?

Comment: Because it's a variable, not a field: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/

Comment: Great! And `$$this.value` relates to an entry with `identifier c`, right? That's something I can't get together.

Comment: Well... Not really. ;) ´$filter´ effectively loops over all items in an array and gives you access to each element using a variable (´$$this´ in our case). And for every item it checks our condition against it. The condition I wrote uses boolean logic to say that **either** ´identifier´ needs to be ´"a"´ **OR BOTH** (that's the `$and` bit) the ´identifier´ field needs to be ´"a"´ **AND** the `value` field needs to be greater than 5.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. You are awesome - have a nice day!